# read fastq file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, fastq

I have a fastq file like this (part of the file):

```
@A80HNBABXX:4:1:1344:2224#0/1
AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG  
+
\\YYWX\PX^YT[TVYaTY]^\^H\`^`a`\UZU__TTbSbb^\a^^^`[GOVVXLXMV[Y_^a^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  
@A80HNBABXX:4:1:1515:2211#0/1
TTAGAAACTATGGGATTATTCACTCCCTAGGTACTGAGAATGGAAACTTTCTTTGCCTTAATCGTTGACATCCCCTCTTTTAGGTTCTTGCTTCCTAACA  
+  
ee^e^\`ad`eeee\dd\ddddYeebdd\ddaYbdcYc`\bac^YX[V^\Ybb]]^bdbaZ]ZZ\^K\^]VPNME][`_``Ubb_bYddZbbbYbbYT^_  
@A80HNBABXX:4:1:1538:2220#0/1
CTGAGTAAATCATATACTCAATGATTTTTTTATGTGTGTGCATGTGTGCTGTTGATATTCTTCAGTACCAAAACCCATCATCTTATTTGCATAGGGAAGT  
+
fff^fd\c^d^Ycac`dcdcded`effdfedb]beeeeecd^ddccdddddfff`eaeeeffdTecacaLV[QRPa\\a\`]aY]ZZ[XYcccYcZ\\]Y  
@A80HNBABXX:4:1:1666:2222#0/1
CTGCCAGCACGCTGTCACCTCTCAATAACAGTGAGTGTAATGGCCATACTCTTGATTTGGTTTTTGCCTTATGAATCAGTGGCTAAAAATATTATTTAAT  
+
deeee`bbcddddad\bbbbeee\ecYZcc^dd^ddd\\`]``L`ccabaVJ`MZ^aaYMbbb__PYWY]RWNUUab`Y`BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

The FASTQ file uses four lines per sequence. Line 1 begins with a '@' character and is followed by a sequence identifier. Line 2 is the DNA sequence letters. Line 3 begins with a '+' character. Line 4 encodes the quality values for the sequence in Line 2 (the part after "+" and before the next "@", and must contain the same number of symbols as letters in the sequence.

i want to read the fastq file into a dictionary like this (the key is the DNA sequence and the value is the quality value, and the line starting with "@" and "+" can be discarded):

```
{'AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG':'\YYWX\PX^YT[TVYaTY]^\^H`^a\UZU__TTbSbb^\a^^^[GOVVXLXMV[Y_^a^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',
 'CTGAGTAAATCATATACTCAATGATTTTTTTATGTGTGTGCATGTGTGCTGTTGATATTCTTCAGTACCAAAACCCATCATCTTATTTGCATAGGGAAGT':'fff^fd\c^d^Ycacdcdcdedeffdfedb]beeeeecd^ddccdddddfffeaeeeffdTecacaLV[QRPa\a`]aY]ZZ[XYcccYcZ\]Y ',
    ....}
```

I write the following code but it does not give me what I want. Can anyone help me to fix/improve my code?

```
class fastq(object):
def __init__(self,filename):
    self.filename = filename
    self.__sequences = {}

def parse_file(self):
    symbol=['@','+']
    """Stores both the sequence and the quality values for the sequence"""
    f = open(self.filename,'rU')
    for lines in self.filename:
        if symbol not in lines.startwith()
        data = f.readlines()
return data
```

Comment: You need to be more specific- "does not give me what I want" doesn't tell us what you DO want.  Please explain the difference between the behavior you're getting and the behavior you want.

Comment: i want to read the fastq file into a dictionary like this (the key is the DNA sequence and the value is the quality value, and the line starting with "@" and "+" can be discarded):

Comment: something like {'AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG:'\YYWX\PX^YT[TVYaTY]^\^H`^a\UZU__TTbSbb^\a^^^[GOVVXLXMV[Y_^a^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB', 'CTGAGTAAATCATATACTCAATGATTTTTTTATGTGTGTGCATGTGTGCTGTTGATATTCTTCAGTACCAAAACCCATCATCTTATTTGCATAGGGAAGT': 'fff^fd\c^d^Ycacdcdcdedeffdfedb]beeeeecd^ddccdddddfffeaeeeffdTecacaLV[QRPa\a`]aY]ZZ[XYcccYcZ\]Y ',....}

Comment: Edit the question, don't just dump text into the comments!

Comment: This is not an exact answer, but if you are dealing with fasq maybe you should check the Biopython library, SeqIO module (http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO-module.html). Just in case you're reinventing the wheel coding a parser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty quick and efficient way of doing it:

```
def parse_file(self):
    with open(self.filename, 'r') as f:
        content = f.readlines()

        # Recreate content without lines that start with @ and +
        content = [line for line in content if not line[0] in '@+']

        # Now the lines you want are alternating, so you can make a dict
        # from key/value pairs of lists content[0::2] and content[1::2]
        data = dict(zip(content[0::2], content[1::2]))

    return data
```

Comment: what if a fastq file is 10GB in size f.readlines() reads all lines to memory ?

Comment: @FadelBerakdar There is obviously a solution to this problem that iterates through the file but this is outside the scope of the question as stated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think use the reads as the key is good idea, what if you got exactly the same read. But any way if you want to do it:

```
In [9]:
with open('temp.fastq') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
head=[item[:-1] for item in lines[::4]] #get rid of '\n'
read=[item[:-1] for item in lines[1::4]]
qual=[item[:-1] for item in lines[3::4]]
dict(zip(read, qual))

Out[9]:

{'AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG': '\\\\YYWX\\PX^YT[TVYaTY]^\\^H\\`^`a`\\UZU__TTbSbb^\\a^^^`[GOVVXLXMV[Y_^a^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',
 'CTGAGTAAATCATATACTCAATGATTTTTTTATGTGTGTGCATGTGTGCTGTTGATATTCTTCAGTACCAAAACCCATCATCTTATTTGCATAGGGAAGT': 'fff^fd\\c^d^Ycac`dcdcded`effdfedb]beeeeecd^ddccdddddfff`eaeeeffdTecacaLV[QRPa\\\\a\\`]aY]ZZ[XYcccYcZ\\\\]Y',
 'CTGCCAGCACGCTGTCACCTCTCAATAACAGTGAGTGTAATGGCCATACTCTTGATTTGGTTTTTGCCTTATGAATCAGTGGCTAAAAATATTATTTAAT': 'deeee`bbcddddad\\bbbbeee\\ecYZcc^dd^ddd\\\\`]``L`ccabaVJ`MZ^aaYMbbb__PYWY]RWNUUab`Y`BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',
 'TTAGAAACTATGGGATTATTCACTCCCTAGGTACTGAGAATGGAAACTTTCTTTGCCTTAATCGTTGACATCCCCTCTTTTAGGTTCTTGCTTCCTAACA': 'ee^e^\\`ad`eeee\\dd\\ddddYeebdd\\ddaYbdcYc`\\bac^YX[V^\\Ybb]]^bdbaZ]ZZ\\^K\\^]VPNME][`_``Ubb_bYddZbbbYbbYT^_'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function from Bio, like this:

```
    from Bio import SeqIO

    myf=mydir+myfile
    startlist=[]
    for record in SeqIO.parse(myf, "fastq"):
       startlist.append(str(record.seq)) #or without 'str'
```